# Centre align an image from vertically and horizontally both

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to make an image centre aligned horizontally and vertically both using CSS.

Consider below code where the container is the only element available in the body. I want inside image to be at the mid of the container from left, right, top and bottom.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
 <img name="img.png" width="100" height="100" />
</div>enter code here
</body>
```

Comment: please explain what do you mean by responsive?

Comment: i just want an image to be compressing in width at each pixel when width is compressed, also heigh to be compressing when height is compressed. individually responsive in height and width.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more readable for visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You've to set width as a percentage:

```
<div id="responsive-img">
<img src="yourimage.jpg">
</div>

#responsive-img {
    width:50%;
}

#responsive-img img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Height will be automatically adjusted. [Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/WmcaE/) and resize the window.

That's cross-browser too ;-)

Comment: you are great you understood what he said.. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green ahahah :) I'm not native English speaker either, so it's easier  for us to understand each other

Comment: this is width responsive only, not responsive in height

Comment: @BalramSingh Any browser newer than IE6 will adapt the image's height to its width.